# Class diagram multiplicity confusion

Tags: class, uml, class-diagram

I am trying to draw a class diagram but i am not sure if what i am doing is correct or not.

Scenario
**In this university there is a rule that at most two lecturers teach a course. Every lecturer only teaches 0 to two courses.**

[image]

Comment: Looks good, where's your doubt hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct; as a mnemotechnic you can read it as a sentence

"Lecturer teaches [0..2] Course(s)"

and

"Course is taught by [1..2] Lecturer(s)"

> The multiplicity attached to the target end denotes the possible cardinalities of the set of target instances selected by the pairing of
>   a qualified instance and a qualifier value.

(http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta1/PDF/ chapter 11.5 Associations)